# Is it possible to have a good first year in Sakuna: Of Rice and Ruin?

Tags: sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin

Is it possible to have a good first year and avoid Tauemon's poisonous (not-poisonous) hometown cooking?

Like, the year isn't likely to be good, since Sakuna's just starting out, but I got to level 5 my first year, due to me trying to go for a combat-focused run, and I wonder how good it could've been and if there's an alternate cutscene.